# Munin aggregation not working (summing CPU time across servers)

Tags: monitoring, munin

I am trying to get an aggregated graph of CPU usage across some servers. I have come up with this so far:

```
[totals]
    update no
    contacts no

    lb_cpu.graph_title LB Total User CPU
    lb_cpu.user.sum lb1.example.com:cpu.user lb2.example.com:cpu.user
```

Unfortunately graph generation does not work. The logs show this error:

```
2015/07/22 07:21:15 [RRD ERROR] rrdtool graph did not generate the image (make sure there are data to graph).
2015/07/22 07:21:15 [WARNING] Could not draw graph "/var/cache/munin/www/totals/lb_cpu-day.png": /var/cache/munin/www/totals/lb_cpu-day.png
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong with my config?

Thanks

Update: I updated my example to reflect what I was REALLY doing - i.e. I was not adding a group to the aggregated node name, and using nodes from another group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your mail on the munin-users mailing list.
I may have a former version of Munin ; my configuration looks rather like this:

```
[example.com;totals]

    lb_cpu.graph_title LB Total User CPU
    lb_cpu.user.label User CPU

    lb_cpu.user.sum \
        example.com;lb1:cpu.user \
        example.com;lb2:cpu.user
```

Maybe it needs the group for each existing node?

I also graph the different values summed but I don't think it is the problem here.
Of course, nodes lb1 and lb2 must exist inside the example.com group (and you may adapt ; maybe it is "example.com;lb1.example.com" and so on).

I hope this helps!

Regards

Comment: Exactly the issue! I was actually referencing nodes from another (implicitly created) group in my non-group aggregate node! Good spot!

Comment: Note also that the `lb_cpu.user.label User CPU` line is **required** for the entry to be shown in the graph. That was at least the issue I had when faced with a similar problem